# Should i return an Aggregate root in Repository?

Tags: nestjs, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm reading `clean architecture`.

`MyEntity` extends `AggregateRoot`.

And every time needs to find a record in database, I call repository method to find that, then convert the result to `MyEntity`, and apply an event to it.

e.g.

Entity use-case:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyUseCases {
  constructor(private myFactory: MyFactory) {}

  async myMethod(id: number) {
    const result = await this.myFactory.findById(data);
    // do business logic.
  }
}
```

and the created factory (If the factory convention usage here is correct!):

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFactory implements IEntityFactory<MyEntity> {
  constructor(private readonly myRepository: MyRepository) {}
  async findOneById(id: number): Promise<MyEntity> {
    const schemaRecord = await this.myRepository.findById(id);
    const myEntity = new MyEntity(schemaRecord.toJSON());
    // myEntity.apply(); 
    return myEntity;
  }
}
```

Docs says, lower layers must not depends to upper layers in clean arch.
So I'm using this Factory class as a `port` to convert results to aggregate root instances, instead of converting ORM results in repository to Aggregate root.

Infrastructure Layer:

- Database

  - Repositories
    MyRepository
  - Schema

Application Layer:

- UseCases
  MyUseCase
- Ports
  MyFactory

Domain Layer:

- Models
  MyEntity

Am I in a wrong way?